# Como pegar o dia atual

Tags: c#

Como faço para exibir o dia atual em um programa? Porém eu não queria pegar o zero a esquerda. Por exemplo: o dia 01 quero que seja 1, o dia 02 quero que seja 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A base para o que você precisa é o `DateTime.Today` (ou `DateTime.Now`, a diferença entre eles é que o `Now` contém a hora).

Isso retorna a data atual, num objeto do tipo `DateTime`, para converter para `string` com a formatação específica, é possível usar o método `ToString`.

A formatação que você quer é `d/M/yyyy`

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("d/M/yyyy");
```

Se quiser retornar apenas o dia, em string terá que usar o formato `"d "` (note o espaço após o "d"), porque o d por si só representa um formato padrão.

Porém, tenha em mente que a estrutura `DateTime` contém membros como `Day`, `Month`, `Year`, entre outros. Provavelmente, você deve estar precisando de um destes.

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WNqhq8)

Comment: Dessa forma o dia de hoje por exemplo ficaria 3/10/2018? Se eu quiser pegar somente o dia, posso colocar o "d" dentro do ToString?

Comment: @GuilhermeWayne Fiz uma edição na resposta.

Comment: @GuilhermeWayne Voccê pode usar também o DateTime.Now (https://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-now)

Comment: Muito obrigado LINQ ajudou bastante. PauloHDSouza me ajudou bastante tbm com esse site